# trying to play video and record user experesion with camera (angular)

Tags: ios, angular, iphone

i am trying to play a video and record the user expresion to that video, it is working on the pc but i can't get it fixed on the ios (phone) device. It does not seem to record the video. This is the code i have:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { BlobServiceClient, AnonymousCredential } from "@azure/storage-blob";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-videoplayer',
  templateUrl: './videoplayer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./videoplayer.component.css']
})
export class VideoplayerComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('externalVideo') externalVideo!: ElementRef<HTMLVideoElement>;

  videoLink: string = '';
  isRecording = false;
  private mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder | null = null;
  private sastoken = "";

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.videoLink = params['videolink'];
    });
    this.initCamera();
  }

  private async initCamera() {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
      this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'video/webm' });
      this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {   
        if (event.data.size > 0) {
          this.uploadToAzure(event.data);
        }
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error accessing camera:', error);
    }
  }

  startPlaybackAndRecording() {
    if (this.externalVideo && this.externalVideo.nativeElement) {
      this.externalVideo.nativeElement.play();
    }
    this.startRecording();
  }

  startRecording() {
    if (this.mediaRecorder && this.mediaRecorder.state === 'inactive') {
      this.mediaRecorder.start(30000); // Record in 30-second chunks
      this.isRecording = true;
    }
  }

  stopRecording() {
    if (this.mediaRecorder && this.mediaRecorder.state === 'recording') {
      this.mediaRecorder.stop();
      this.isRecording = false;
    }

    if (this.externalVideo && this.externalVideo.nativeElement) {
      this.externalVideo.nativeElement.pause();
    }

  }

  private async uploadToAzure(videoBlob: Blob) {
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net?${this.sastoken}`, new AnonymousCredential());
    const containerName = 'xxxx';
    const blobName = this.generateBlobName();

    try {
      const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
      const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
      await blockBlobClient.uploadData(videoBlob);
      console.log("Upload to Azure Storage successful");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading to Azure Storage", error);
    }
  }

  private generateBlobName() {
    const timestamp = new Date();
    const dateString = timestamp.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    const timeString = timestamp.toISOString().split('T')[1].replace(/:/g, 'H').split('.')[0] + 's';
    return `${dateString}/${timeString}.webm`;
  }
}
```